# How to resolve this Linker error of BOOST Log 1 .72?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, linker

A bit of background information.

I have a source code-base that should work for two platforms/compiler:

- Windows 10: MinGw: x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0
- Raspberry PI 4/ Linux: Raspberry-gcc8.3.0-r2

The HostPc works with Windows 10.

After building the BOOST Lib with the commands:

```
call bootstrap.bat mingw
call .\b2
```

This is the build result:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

:::::::::::::::::::::::\Boost_1_72_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

:::::::::::::::::::::::\Boost_1_72_0\stage\lib
```

The include and lib paths are part of my project configurations (Windows/Raspberry).

At this point it is possible to use the functionalities of the Boost-Lib.
For example: boost/asio
And a TCP/IP connection works.

Now to the problem:
I want to use the BOOST Log functionality.

Header-File:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
```

Code-File:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "This is an informational severity message";
```

The Linker-Error (Windonws/MinGW)looks like:

```
Linking Project:executableLCB.EXE
:::::::\default/../CLogging.cpp:30: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt57trivial6logger3getEv'
:::::::\default/../CLogging.cpp:30: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt57trivial6logger3getEv'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::record::reset()':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/core/record.hpp:157: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt511record_view11public_data7destroyEPKS3_'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::record boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::features<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level> >
>::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level const> > >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level const> > const&)':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:456: undefined reference to '__imp__ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt54core19get_logging_enabledEv'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::record&)':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:508: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt53aux15stream_providerIcE17allocate_compoundERNS1_6recordE'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release()':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:493: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt53aux15stream_providerIcE16release_compoundEPNS4_15stream_compoundE'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex>::lock_shared() const':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/threading_models.hpp:74: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt53aux14light_rw_mutex11lock_sharedEv'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex>::unlock_shared() const':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/threading_models.hpp:78: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt53aux14light_rw_mutex13unlock_sharedEv'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level)':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp:135: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt57sources3aux18get_severity_levelEv'
CLogging.o: In function 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::record boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity,
boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level const> > >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level const> > const&)':
:::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:259: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt54core11open_recordERKNS1_13attribute_setE'
CLogging.o::::::::\default/../../Project/Boost_1_72_0/boost/log/core/core.hpp:308: undefined reference to '__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt54core16push_record_moveERNS1_6recordE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [0.mk:182: executableLCB.EXE] Error 1
```

Some other post explain that this deal with the static and dynamic linking. I have tried different ways without success.

[linker error while linking boost log tutorial (undefined references)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references)

1. Question: How to resolve this linker error for the windows configuration?
2. Question: How to build and link the Boost lib static, to have all the functionality that the application needs at one place.
3. Question: How the Boost-lib could be build, that both configuration MinGW (call bootstrap.bat mingw) and GCC are on the drive at the same time?

Thx in advance
Stony

**Update**

The root cause of this error is, that I have build the wrong libraries:
For the MinGW case (OS: Windows architecure:x84_64) the host is also the target.
So the command to build the Boost library with the right configuration with all modules is:

```
call bootstrap.bat mingw
call .\b2 toolset=gcc target-os=windows --address-model=64 --link=static --variant=debug threading=multi --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-container --with-context --with-contract --with-coroutine --with-date_time --with-exception --with-fiber --with-filesystem --with-graph --with-graph_parallel --with-headers --with-iostreams --with-locale --with-log --with-math --with-mpi --with-program_options --with-python --with-random --with-regex --with-serialization --with-stacktrace --with-system --with-test --with-thread --with-timer --with-type_erasure --with-wave
```

Linker command of the application part should be extend with:

```
..\Boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_log-mgw81-mt-x64-1_72.a
..\Boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw81-mt-x64-1_72.a
```

Thx

Comment: Show your linker command line, which is surely missing the Boost Log library.

Comment: Youre right, in the error of the first post, the -`lboost_log` flag is not part of the linker argument. If I put this flag in the argument list of the linker, the file is not there: `..\mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_log`

Comment: The Boost Log Libs in the folder

 `\Boost_1_72_0\stage\lib`

are

`libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log_setup-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log_setup-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log_setup-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib`
`libboost_log_setup-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory containing the Boost libraries to your linker search path:

```
-L/YOUR_PATH_GOES_HERE/Boost_1_72_0/stage/lib
```

And then link the particular version of the library you want to use:

```
-lboost_log-vc142-mt-x64-1_72
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case Raspberry PI 4/ Linux: Raspberry-gcc8.3.0-r2 the build failed:
(Host-OS=Windows, Target-OS=Linux, architecure:arm)

I have insert the following line into the file
Boost_1_72_0\libs\beast\tools\user-config.jam

```
using gcc : C:\\SysGCC\\Raspberry\\bin\\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe : <ranlib>C:\\SysGCC\\Raspberry\\bin\\arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib.exe <archiver>C:\\SysGCC\\Raspberry\\bin\\arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar.exe ;
```

Build boost Lib:

```
call bootstrap.bat gcc
call .\b2 target-os=linux --address-model=32 --link=static --variant=debug threading=multi --with-log --with-thread
```

The summary errors is:

```
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:37: error: '::sysconf' has not been declared
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:58:46: error: '_SC_PAGESIZE' was not declared in this scope

...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\atomic\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\libboost_atomic-gcc8-mt-x64-1_72.so.1.72.0...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\posix\object_name.o...
...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\libboost_date_time-gcc8-mt-x64-1_72.so.1.72.0...
...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\libboost_filesystem-gcc8-mt-x64-1_72.so.1.72.0...
...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\regex\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\libboost_regex-gcc8-mt-x64-1_72.so.1.72.0...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\posix\object_name.o...
...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\chrono\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\libboost_chrono-gcc8-mt-x64-1_72.so.1.72.0...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\event.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\severity_level.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\event.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\severity_level.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\thread\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\pthread\thread.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\thread_id.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\thread_id.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\thread\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\pthread\thread.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\setup\init_from_settings.o...
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\visibility-hidden\setup\init_from_settings.o...
```

This post describes the procedure for an older Boost version:

[Cross-Compiling Boost on Windows for Raspberry Pi using SysGCC Toolchain and MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574295/cross-compiling-boost-on-windows-for-raspberry-pi-using-sysgcc-toolchain-and-min)